# No moving on iPad

Tags: ios, candy-box-2

I'm playing Candy Box 2 as an app on my iPad and when I jump in the ocean it says to move the phone up and down to move the character. I've tried tilting and moving the iPad but it's not working and my character stays at the same level the whole time.

Does anyone know how to make it move on the iPad?

Comment: You'd need a keyboard with up and down arrow keys. Or there may be a solution if you Are jailbroken.

Comment: Check is "Lock rotation" is on.